# Unable to run dash_interactive_graphviz

Tags: python, plotly-dash, graphviz

I created a huge Graphviz Network, which I now want to spice up with some interactivity. For this goal I discovered the package [dash_interactive_graphviz](https://github.com/BusinessOptics/dash_interactive_graphviz). From my understanding I can simple provide my existing graph, but I'm already failing to execute the provided sample (see below):

```
import dash_interactive_graphviz

dot_source = """
digraph  {
  node[style="filled"]
  a ->b->d
  a->c->d
}
"""

dash_interactive_graphviz.DashInteractiveGraphviz(
    id="graph",
    dot_source=dot_source
)
```

The package itself and all requirements are fulfilled. I run the sample code from above in Visual Studio Code, but nothing happens (no output, no message, no error).

Anybody who can point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction, just need a few steps. I think you can check out this example here to run your file:
https://github.com/BusinessOptics/dash_interactive_graphviz/blob/master/usage.py

```
import dash_interactive_graphviz
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

initial_dot_source = """
digraph  {
node[style="filled"]
a ->b->d
a->c->d
}
"""

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            dash_interactive_graphviz.DashInteractiveGraphviz(id="gv"),
            style=dict(flexGrow=1, position="relative"),
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H3("Selected element"),
                html.Div(id="selected"),
                html.H3("Dot Source"),
                dcc.Textarea(
                    id="input",
                    value=initial_dot_source,
                    style=dict(flexGrow=1, position="relative"),
                ),
                html.H3("Engine"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="engine",
                    value="dot",
                    options=[
                        dict(label=engine, value=engine)
                        for engine in [
                            "dot",
                            "fdp",
                            "neato",
                            "circo",
                            "osage",
                            "patchwork",
                            "twopi",
                        ]
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            style=dict(display="flex", flexDirection="column"),
        ),
    ],
    style=dict(position="absolute", height="100%", width="100%", display="flex"),
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("gv", "dot_source"), Output("gv", "engine")],
    [Input("input", "value"), Input("engine", "value")],
)
def display_output(value, engine):
    return value, engine


@app.callback(Output("selected", "children"), [Input("gv", "selected")])
def show_selected(value):
    return html.Div(value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```